# Android addView and removeView in the same method

Tags: android, imageview

I'm calling this method that should redraw a pointer in the position given in every call.

```
ImageView ivPointer=null;
public void moveCursor(Bitmap bmPuntero, int x, int y)
{
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamelayout);

    if (ivPointer!=null)
        rl.removeView(ivPointer);


    ivPointer = new ImageView(this);

    ivPointer.setImageBitmap(bmPuntero);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(65, 65);
    params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y;
    rl.addView(ivPointer, params);

}
```

The result is that the bitmap isn't showed. If I remove the lines that remove the view, I see how the bitmap is drawn multiple times, so the add part should be correct.

Comment: have you tried moving your layout outside of your method?

Comment: I have tried it now and same results

Comment: It was related to the frequency I was calling the method. If I call with less frequency I see the image flashing every time I update the position calling this method.

Comment: I was thinking of that as well too, perhaps it is actually happening or the pointer is redrawn but method is called very fast that you can't even see it anymore and since pointer is not null, it will be remove from the parent layout. Probably putting some delay but it depends on you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
   // Somewhere (in onCreate of the Activity for example):

   RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gamelayout);
   ImageView ivPointer = initPointer(this, bmPuntero); // Get image from somewhere
   rl.addView(ivPointer);
}


// To update the cursor's po
public static void moveCursor(ImageView pointer, int x, int y) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) pointer.getLayoutParams();
    params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y;

    pointer.setLayoutParams(params);
    pointer.requestLayout(); // Refresh the layout
}

// Call this method to initialise the pointer (in onCreate of your Activity
// for example)
public static ImageView initPointer(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
    // Define the LayoutParams
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(65, 65);
    params.leftMargin = DEFAULT_POS_X; // TODO: Constants to be defined
    params.topMargin = DEFAULT_POS_Y;

    // Init the ImageView
    ImageView pointer = new ImageView(context);
    pointer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    pointer.setLayoutParams(params);

    return pointer;
}
```